# Android: Arrow down control button in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, button, navigation-drawer

I'm using a navigation drawer and I need to know which control is this arrow down button. Is this a special control or just an ImageButton? Thanks.

Source: https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content

[image: Arrow down button]

Comment: From where do you get that screenshot? is this the sample made by you?

Comment: @MukeshRana I updated the question.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such special control in NavigationDrawer , that will be a simple ImageView or ImageButton.